# Django database reconnect

Tags: python, django

Django's backend ([firebird](http://code.google.com/p/django-firebird/)) problem reconnecting to database was fixed as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125504/django-persistent-database-connection) by disabling request finishing signal. It works on the development server, but when the project was deployed with mod_wsgi connections it again started to reinitialize for each request. How can I fix it? Thanks.

p.s my connection is very expensive (about 1sec.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the connections aren't being created from distinct processes. Depending on how you run mod_wsgi then multiple processes could be involved in accepting and handling requests. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

Make sure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode with default of a single process and see if observed behaviour changes.