# Why doesn't django support connection pool?

Tags: python, django

I wonder why django doesn't support connection pool? I can't bear open/close connection every request. I try to solve it, but hasn't a good solution.

I try to use [mysql_pool](http://node.to/wordpress/2010/02/11/database-connection-pool-solution-for-django-mysql/), but fail:

```
TypeError: init() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: `__init__` expects only 1 argument and you're passing 3, why?

Comment: Are you running django as CGI (instead of something like as WSGI or mod_python)?

Answer (score 13):

EDITED: look at [Django persistent database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125504/django-persistent-database-connection) (feature introduced in 1.6).

> Persistent connections avoid the overhead of re-establishing a connection to the database in each request. They’re controlled by the CONN_MAX_AGE parameter which defines the maximum lifetime of a connection. It can be set independently for each database.

Comment: It will. Django explicitly closes connection on end of request.

Comment: @Suor: It will indeed - shame on me.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a discussion about why django did not add pooling to the core:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/NwY9CHM4xpU

Generally speaking it's because third party applications such as pgbouncer do it better.

Comment: Awesome answer. Btw [Posgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) tells: "Some client side software (like Java EE / JPA / Hibernate) always pools connections, so built-in pooling in PostgreSQL would then be wasteful duplication."