# Django Mysql Connection Pooling

Tags: mysql, django, sqlalchemy

What is the best way to establish connection pooling for MySQL connections in Django..?

I have read a couple of blogs like [SQLAlchemy](http://menendez.com/blog/mysql-connection-pooling-django-and-sqlalchemy/)

Can anyone suggest standard practices for the same.. I am running a B2C application on django and the number of simultaneous requests may hit 10000..

Comment: django >=1.6 have auto pooling, if you using django older virsion you can use : https://github.com/smartfile/django-mysqlpool/.

Comment: Can you point me to a doc for version >=1.6 which states connection pooling is auto..

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/databases/#persistent-connections

Comment: @YogeshDwivedi.. It only talks about persistence of connections with a max age.. What I am looking for is connection pooling..

Comment: why should not : https://github.com/smartfile/django-mysqlpool ?

Comment: @yogesh.. It looks like a sub standard solution ..

Comment: Unfortunately, django-mysqlpool looks like it's unmaintained. The most recent version on PyPI doesn't support Python3 (though github does), and the most recent commit is from May 2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't django support connection pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546059/why-doesnt-django-support-connection-pool)

Comment: @GEITPL_Dev It's not auto pooling, just does not close connections immediately

Answer (score -1):

So for anyone still visiting this an unsatisfied with Django built in connection pooling (which has zero configuration and in all honesty I'm not too sure works), this project although years old since its last commit still works!

https://github.com/djangonauts/djorm-ext-pool

Comment: The Django pool isn't a pool. Its one thread - one connection.

Comment: I see, anyways we're using djorm-ext-pool