# Django: Pooling MySQL DB Connections

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, connection-pooling

I have a Django App with a pretty standard server stack

- DB Backend : MySQL
- WSGI Server : Gunicorn
- Async worker class : Gevent

I want Django to pool MySQL connections rather than creating connections on every request.

Starting 1.6, Django has introduced [persistent connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#persistent-connections) but there are [issues](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/996) with async workers.

Hence, either a different MySQL backend is required or app level connection pooling. I've read several of them. Some of them are very old articles. Following are some:

**Django MySQL backends**

1. [django-mysqlpool](https://github.com/smartfile/django-mysqlpool)

**App level Connection pool**

1. [with SQL Alchemy](http://sonofacoder.com/index.php/django-mysql-connection-pooling-and-ssl/)
2. [another with SQL Alchemy](http://techualization.blogspot.in/2012/09/database-connection-pooling-in-django.html)

**Some Patches are also available**

1. [Django Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6712190/820410)

**Some other approaches**

1. [MySQL DB Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html)

I'm really confused as to which approach among these is the best way to pool connections? Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't django support connection pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546059/why-doesnt-django-support-connection-pool)

Answer (score 1):

This project still works on Django 1.9, and worked well for us.

https://github.com/djangonauts/djorm-ext-pool

Answer (score 0):

**your demand**

> want  pool MySQL connections rather than creating connections on
>   every request.

**my suggest**

1. in db level

> Indicating that your application is **IO-intensive**, so the proposal
>   is to use mysql conn pool.
>  may be u can use thirdpart **mysql pool**

2. in app level

> in app level no use connection pooling. But mostly use the **cache**
>   ,may be redis cache etc,this can minus the connection number.

3. in webserver level

> in your server socalled *WSGI Server* . It is ligntweight so not
>   pooling implement,u can refact to use queue to enhance the connection
>   reused. or base Gevent to refact **event_queue**.

Hope this may can give you some help.