Django:: ImproperlyConfigured: Pooling doesn't support persistent connections
I've recently upgraded to Django 5.1 and configured the database pooling option with the following settings:
DATABASES["default"]["OPTIONS"] = {
    "pool": {"min_size": 2, "max_size": 4, "timeout": 10}
}
DATABASES["default"]["CONN_MAX_AGE"] = None


However, I encountered the following error: ImproperlyConfigured: Pooling doesn't support persistent connections.
I understand that removing CONN_MAX_AGE = None will resolve this issue, but I would like to gain a deeper understanding of this limitation. Specifically, is the restriction on using persistent connections with pooling a constraint unique to Django's implementation, or does it extend to PostgreSQL (or other databases) in general? Additionally, what are the underlying reasons for this incompatibility?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546059/why-doesnt-django-support-connection-pool
Does this question contain all of the information you were asking?

I've been following this. Django didn’t initially add pooling because third-party apps were handling it much better; that was around 2013. However, they finally introduced it in version 5.1. Although database connection persistence has been available, my question now is why can't I use both(pooling and persistence)?

This is the link to the original proposal: https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/NwY9CHM4xpU. I should also point out that I am not very experienced with databases. I have been using the ORM and Django settings for database tasks

The Connection pooling option in Django 5.1 uses psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool to handle the pooling logic and Django doesn't implement the logic on it's own. Django simply returns the connection back to this pool after each request and leaves the handling of closing the connection to it since that's supposed to be handled by the pool.
The ConnectionPool class has it's own options which you can configure by the dictionary you pass to the pool option. If you want something similar to CONN_MAX_AGE you can configure the max_lifetime argument.

Thank you! I checked it out and will explore the additional options I can pass through the connection pool.
