# django with mysql what does 'maximum number of connections'?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, mysql-python

I am writting simple application which django that can be used internally inside my office. probably 1000 people i say. I dont have any session handling, user handling. It is just a store/view process in the django.

What i understood?

1) django closes reopens the database connection on each request. 
2) mysql has a threshold of maximum number of connections to be made.

My Question?

1) maximum number of connections ->  Let's say 10 users accessing my URL through their desktop browser. Does that mean Django creates 10 independent connections to handle request ?

2) whatever i use persistent/non-persistent, as a programmer do i need to take care in the coding part?. ie: do we need any check like in Django?

```
if <Connection is valid>  
then 
    Initiate transaction
```

Kindly clarify  my questions?. Forgive me if the question is very basic.

Comment: For a 1,000-user app you should not be worrying about this at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but just for my understanding purpose, i am asking. Kindly advise?

Answer (score 6):

According to Django documentation related to the database, Django opens a connection to the database when it first makes a database query. It keeps this connection open and reuses it in subsequent requests. Django closes the connection once it exceeds the maximum age defined by CONN_MAX_AGE or when it isn’t usable any longer.

The default value for CONN_MAX_AGE is 0, preserving the historical behavior of closing the database connection at the end of each request. For persistent connections, you need to set CONN_MAX_AGE to any positive number of seconds. For unlimited persistent connections, set it to None.

So answer to your first question depends on the setting of the CONN_MAX_AGE flag value. If it's set to 0 then yes for each of 10 users, it will use 10 different connections.

In answer to the second question, I think we don't need to take care of checking for valid connections because I believe the Django database layer performs everything.

You can look over the following URLs, everything is described over there.

[Django Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/)

[Django Persistent DB connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502814/django-persistent-db-connections-a-different-approach)

Hope this will help you.