# Is there any way to restart postgres on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I deploy a Rails app using Unicorn. After every deployment and after every tweak I do to the `DB_POOL` I see postgres still hold some connections as idle and new changes are very inconsistently making me wondering If is restarting at all the service after every pool change.

I haven't found any documentation regarding this. Is there any similar command to pg_ctl on Heroku?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restart Heroku Postgres Dev DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949084/restart-heroku-postgres-dev-db)

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is flush your connection pool.... but that said, it sounds like you have an application bug, probably where you're leaking transactions, if this actually makes any difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot restart your Postgres database on Heroku. If you have lingering connections, it's likely an app issue. Try in stalling the pg-extras plugin and looking for `IDLE` connections:

- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras

Also, you can try setting up a custom ActiveRecord connection in your `after_fork` block and enabling the connection reaper, which should clean up any lingering dead connections it finds:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Comment: Thanks. Already did that before but still getting idle connections.