# Restarting Heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

I'm runnning a rails app on heroku with a postgres database hosted by Amazon. I tried a migration that would never end (over 40 minutes) and ran it a few too many times. Now I have 20 connections open to the database, which is the maximum, and no idea how to close those connections.

What can I do?

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11951744/139687

Comment: @babinho, I already saw that. It's not a matter of my application holding on to connections so the first part doesn't help. And since I'm already at my max number of connections, I can't run the sql from the second half of the answer to close connections.

Comment: run `heroku restart --app appname`

Comment: @babinho, that has no effect.

Comment: The last thing i can think of is `heroku ps:scale web=0` to turn off your web dynos, and then `heroku ps:scale web=1` but you can do that from the web UI too

Comment: Yea I tried doing that as well. It's seems to be a completely separate issue from the dynos though.

Comment: if you have a postgres database hosted by amazon. connect to that amazon database server and restart it. what does have heroku todo with that?

Comment: @phoet, agreed. How can I access the ec2 database through AWS that Heroku created for me?

Answer (score 5):

If you database is on heroku then you can kill all database connections using a heroku plugin

[heroku-pg-extras](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/)

```
pg:killall [DATABASE]  #  terminates ALL connections
```

To you above command you need to install heroku-pg-extra plugin

Comment: Just as a note it looks like pg:killall was removed from pg extras

Comment: (Seems like more than just a note)