# Heroku and Postgresql and Rails - too many connections error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting the following error with Ruby on Rails, Heroku and Postgresql:

```
PG::Error (FATAL:  too many connections for role "********"
```

I've restarted the server several times to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the site getting a lot of traffic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku "psql: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847144/heroku-psql-fatal-remaining-connection-slots-are-reserved-for-non-replication)

Comment: @sabes You need to configure a maximum number of connections used by Rails, and/or use a connection pool. See the answers on the post I just linked to.

Comment: It's actually just a staging server, so it does not get much traffic at all.

Comment: Craig, is it just the 'pool' property in database.yml that needs to be increased?

Comment: @sabes Increasing the size of your Rails connection pool would allow it to grab *more* connections from PostgreSQL. Your rails app is already trying to use too many connections. You need to *decrease* the number of connections your rails app uses to keep it under `max_connections`. Do *not* just increase `max_connections`; read http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was on a dev-level DB. I upgraded to Crane level production DB and everything should be fine.

Comment: dev (and basic) databases have a max connection limit of 20 - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-starter-tier#limits

Answer (score 3):

Paying Heroku more money isn't always the answer.

I had this problem temporarily when I was running up against the dev-level database's [row limit](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#starter-tier). Deleting rows using the console until I was below the limit solved the issue.

Another potential way you can run into this is if you're using unicorn. The number of connections used is the number of dynos times the number of unicorn workers per dyno. Heroku explains it all [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections), along with a way to configure it in `config/unicorn.rb`.

Also, seeing the number of connections being used can be useful. Just run `heroku pg:info`.