# Fatal database error on Heroku dev

Tags: django, mongodb, heroku

I have a Django app (music streaming service) running on a free hosting account on Heroku with a Postgres database with one web dyno. Yesterday I wrote a script that uploads mp3 files to Heroku, extract meta data, then upload it the files to Amazon S3. When I'm going through this process, I get this error when I try to refresh

```
could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
```

or

```
FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

When I go to postgres.heroku.com to see the statistics, here is what I have :

```
Plan    Dev
Status  available
Data Size   9.0 MB
Tables  0
PG Version  9.1.6
Created December 05, 2012 17:33
```

We have no users yet, in fact, I'm the only one using it at the moment. I'm sure we soon have to upgrade but I'm not sure with what to start. Should we start with the database, get more dynos, or what? I even started thinking of switching to MongoDB as the frequency of read and writing data to the database will be relatively high (incrementing the number of stars and listens per song, number of minutes listened by each user, etc etc).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems you are having resource issues for postgres - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847144/heroku-psql-fatal-remaining-connection-slots-are-reserved-for-non-replication

Comment: With Dev databases you are limited to 20 connections: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#starter-tier  Make sure you are using connection pooling and reusing connections.

Comment: Any links on how to use connection pooling and reuse connections, I've never done that. Also, do you think it helps to add Memcached to lower the database access frequency?

Comment: How are you creating a connection to the database?  How is django setup are you creating lots of threads / workers as that will make a connection per worker.

Comment: No, I have a standard django setup, that is, exactly how it is described in the Heroku documentation. I have `djcelery` installed but I'm not using it for now. Problem occurred only when I was uploading multiple files to Heroku, process it, and from there I upload it to S3. Maybe that's what is creating lots of threads???

Comment: @MohamedTurki I had the same problem a couple days ago. I was also doing the same thing with S3, so that might be a culprit.

Comment: The problem was because I was consuming the 20 connections, also there was a problem with Heroku's end. Now it seems to be working fine, but eventually I'll have to upgrade.