# Should I avoid 'async void' event handlers?

Tags: c#, .net, events, asynchronous, async-await

I know it is considered generally a bad idea to use fire-and-forget `async void` methods to start tasks, because there is no track of the pending task and it is tricky to handle exceptions which might be thrown inside such a method.

*Should I generally avoid `async void` event handlers, as well?* For example,

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        await Task.Delay(2000); // do async work
        // ...
}
```

I can rewrite it like this:

```
Task onFormLoadTask = null; // track the task, can implement cancellation

private void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        this.onFormLoadTask = OnFormLoadTaskAsync(sender, e);
} 

private async Task OnFormLoadTaskAsync(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        await Task.Delay(2000); // do async work
        // ...
}
```

*What are the underwater rocks for async event handlers, besides possible re-entrancy?*

Comment: You should but you can't. Besides that, all the cares you must take when using async void are already required by UI event handlers.

Comment: And reentrancy happens because of asynchronous operations fired by the event handler and not by the use of async-await by itself.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The guideline is to avoid `async void` *except* when used in an event handler, so using `async void` in an event handler is OK.

That said, for *unit testing* reasons I often like to factor out the logic of all `async void` methods. E.g.,

```
public async Task OnFormLoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Delay(2000);
  ...
}

private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await OnFormLoadAsync(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious...  is there a reason why you don't just change `Form_Load`'s access to `public`? It seems like the code would be less verbose that way.

Comment: Oops, never mind... VBer trying to read C# here... I just noticed the return type of `OnFormLoadAsync`. I see now that this makes for a handy trick. Thanks.

Comment: All that said, could you have a look and offer an opinion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28524372/722393). Thanks!

Comment: In WPF is it fine to mark routed event handlers with async? I am not sure how the `Handled` flag on the event args would be checked in such a case...

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: The `Handled` flag *must* be set synchronously; it's not possible to use `async` to make a decision on whether the event is handled or not.

Comment: @StephenCleary so would it be alright to fire off an async void from the top level event handlers for command bindings in WPF? Been reading this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx

But I have been using CommandBinding and RoutedUICommand in my application and was wondering how to best execute my commands asynchronously and provide things like user cancellation etc

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: It's been a while since I've worked with a WPF app, but I've used solutions similar to that in the past. I.e., make the `ICommand.Execute` method `async void`; I consider this acceptable since `ICommand.Execute` is *logically* an event handler.

Comment: @StephenCleary Is your answer also will be good in case there is try-catch inside the method called by the timer? Is there a chance which the logging inside the catch clause will not be written? I'm asking this, since it always had been said that in case of "async void" there is no guarantee for the logging to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NurielZrubavely: If there's logging in the catch clause, it should be run on exception. However, if you're doing "fire and forget" on ASP.NET, then any `async void` method may not complete.

Answer (score 61):

> Should I generally avoid async void event handlers, as well?

Generally event handlers are the one case where a void async method is not a potential code smell.

Now, if you do need to track the task for some reason then the technique you describe is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 8):

If you use ReSharper, a free [ReCommended Extension](https://github.com/prodot/ReCommended-Extension) could be helpful for you. It analyzes the "async void" methods and highlights when used inappropriately.
The extension can distinguish different usages of async void and provide appropriated quick fixes described here: [ReCommended-Extension wiki](https://github.com/prodot/ReCommended-Extension/wiki/Avoid-Async-Void).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, generally async void of event handlers is the only case. If you want to know more about it you can check out a great video here at channel 9 
*`The only case where this kind of fire-and-forget is appropriate is in top-level event-handlers. Every other async method in your code should return "async Task".`*

here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/three-essential-tips-for-async/tip-1-async-void-top-level-event-handlers-only)

Comment: The '_top-level event-handlers_' is a important hint. When using async void event handler on lower level event handler it can cause huge problems with not caught exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the video link, very useful

Comment: The link is broken, it may have been moved here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/three-essential-tips-for-async/tip-1-async-void-top-level-event-handlers-only