# Can't await async extension method

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, async-await, c#-5.0

Situation is pretty simple - I wrote an extension method and made it async with return type `Task<T>`. But when I try to call it using await, compiler throws an error which suggests that the extension method wasn't recognized as async at all. 
Here's my code:

```
public static async Task<NodeReference<T>> CreateWithLabel<T>(this GraphClient client, T source, String label) where T: class
    {
        var node = client.Create(source);
        var url = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey] + "/node/{0}/labels", node.Id);
        var serializedLabel = string.Empty;
        using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new DataContractJsonSerializer(label.GetType()).WriteObject(tempStream, label);
            serializedLabel = Encoding.Default.GetString(tempStream.ToArray());
        }
        var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(serializedLabel);

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            await webClient.UploadDataTaskAsync(url, "POST", bytes);
        }

        return node;
    }


var newNode = await client.CreateWithLabel(new Task(), "Task");
```

Exact error message is this:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Am I doing something wrong or is it a language/compiler limitation?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Tip: if you follow the [TAP conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), other developers will more easily be able to use your `async` methods.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: the method *where* you're calling the extension method should be marked as `async`.

```
public Task<string> MyExtension(this string s) { ... }

public async Task MyCallingMethod()
{    
    string result = await "hi".MyExtension();
}
```

Re-reading this part should make much more sense now:

"The 'await' operator can only be used **within** an async method. "

Comment: I see. Will be more attentive next time.

Comment: @dcastro, you may want to change the signature of `MyCallingMethod` to return a `Task`, `void` is only good for async event handlers.

Comment: @Noseratio I disagree, there are plenty of other scenarios where you'd want "fire and forget" behaviour. I will edit my post though, simply because less experienced users might be surprised by the results of `async void`.

Comment: @dcastro, I disagree too that there are plenty. I'd be interested to learn about any useful scenarios other than [async event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19415646/1768303) (which is obviously not the case here).

Comment: Logging, for example. A service may want to fire a method and trigger some business logic, but return to the client asap. You don't _always_ need to wait for the result of a method. Maybe the word "plenty" was a bit too much, but saying that "void is only good for async event handlers" isn't correct either.

Comment: Although being aware of the side effects of `async void` is very important when going down that road.