# nUnit Assert.That delegate concurrency issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, nunit, task-parallel-library

I am experiencing some temporary dead lock in my code and can't wrap my head around it.

Simple code (I cannot create a simple call chain to reproduce the code in `InvokeChangeEvent`)

```
[Test]
public async void Test()
{
    sut.InvokeChangeEvent("./foo.file");
    // Event is handled by an async handler chaining multiple await resulting in a file write

    // await Task.Delay(3000);

    Assert.That(() => Directory.GetFiles("some dir").Count(), Is.EqualTo(3).After(15000, 300));

}
```

I am aware that y'all (:D) want executable code but I wasn't able to slice it down therefore I hope for some insight by explanation.

What happens: `sut.InvokeChangeEvent` calls an event handler that later calls an `async` event handler which then calls some `async`. The end of the chain results in an `Task.Run` that boils down to write 3 files.

The Assert above is implemented as a delegate with `After` that returns a `DelayedConstraint` and has a very large max time (15 secs) and a small polling interval.

Now when I debug the code the InvokeChangeEvent call is entirely executed to the last Task.Run but when the Task.Run returns, the execution is yielded back to the main thread and the Assert is executed entering the "wait with polling".

However the assert never succeeds. When I debug the issue the return of the Task.Run is always handled **after** the Assert delegate has run (and failed).

I've figured out, that when I place an `await Task.Delay(3000);` before the Assert, then the code executes properly.

As mentioned the system under test has plenty await and Task.Runs chained and I was unable to reproduce the issue with some easy runnable code.

I've been googling around for a while and I cannot figure out why the Task.Run (which is executed on a different thread) yield in a (temporary) deadlock even though the `DelayedConstraint` has an explicit polling interval to allow the main thread to progress.

It looks like the `DelayedConstraint` locks the main thread by some sort of `Thread.Sleep`. `await Task.Delay` does not, I am aware of that. What confuses me is I have checked that I always do an `await` (and never `Task.Result`, etc) and therefore would expect that the file has been written before the Assert has executed.

*(Note: `Thread.Sleep` instead of `await Task.Delay` does not work.)*

Usually the `DelayedConstraint` is used to ensure that file system has properly written all files as I have experienced some delays of the file system dealing with files.

I have some feeling that `async void` event handler may create a situation which I do not understand.

If I manage to create a simple sample, I will update the thread.

Comment: Have you tried `public async Task Test()` rather than `public async void Test()`?

Comment: @Noseratio thanks for the hint, I will test it asap. I wasn't aware that nUnit supported async Task. I was lucky that they extended their Tests to support async at all. How ever as I have no code here I am wondering whether this is going to compile at all as I am not returning a task in the code above.

Comment: Samuel, actually I'm not sure if NUnit supports async methods at all, but chances are higher for `Task` vs `void`. That's the case for VS2012+ unit testing. If NUnit doesn't support it, perhaps you can still return a `Task` and do `Task.Wait()` in your NUnit wrapper.

Comment: @Noseratio it was indeed the async void. As NUnit seems to support async Task I've converted all async voids to it to avoid such stalling. If you make an answer of your comment I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By analogy with VS2012 unit testing, try `async Task` signature rather than `async void` for your test method. This way, NUnit should be able to keep track of the pending task status and inspect exceptions via `Task.Exception`.

The `async void` method is a fire-and-forget concept, by definition. The method returns instantly (precisely, upon the first asynchronous `await` inside it), and then there is no way to handle its completion or any errors possibly thrown inside it. As is, `async void` methods [are only good for event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19415646/1768303), provided exceptions are handled within the method with `try/catch`.