# NUnit async test causing AppDomainUnloadedException

Tags: wcf, nunit, async-await

I have a .NET 4.5 WCF service with async operations. I have integration tests which constructs the service host using NetNamedPipeBinding and hits the operation via a client.

However, each test like this always causes NUnit to report the following:

```
System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. 
This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. 
Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.
```

Everything looks ok to me. Can anyone see what might be causing this? I have a complete code sample on GitHub: https://github.com/devlife/codesamples

Comment: Which version of NUnit do you use? Old versions of course won't work. http://www.anthonysteele.co.uk/async-and-await-with-nunit

Comment: @LexLi this refers to marking NUnit tests as async, not calling async WCF operations. These are just methods that return Task on which you can easily call `.Wait()` or `.Result`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I hope you check his code on GitHub.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the code is checked in.

Comment: Indeed, he is using the latest version, 2.6.3 which should not have such issues.

Comment: @LexLi I'm using NUnit version 2.6.3: <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: @devlife, any chance you're using `async void` for your test methods? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22205708/1768303

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue with Visual Studio 2013 and latest TestDriven.Net. Thus, I think it is nothing wrong with your code, but the NUnit runner you use.

Comment: @Noseratio nope. async Task...

Comment: @LexLi I think you may be right about it being an issue with the test runner.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem. It looks as if the issue are "lenient" completion port threads (in the ThreadPool) that have been used by WCF to handle async IO.

When `ServiceHost.Close()` is used, it will signal all those threads that work is done, but they won't go away immediately, that is, they may outlive the end of the `ServiceHost.Close()` operation. Thus, the "shutdown" procedure races with the actual AppDomain unloading induced by NUnit due to the end of the test run.

Basically, a simple `Thread.Sleep(<a couple of seconds>)` after a `ServiceHost.Close()` "fixes" this :-)

After much searching around on the internet I couldn't find a robust solution for this issue (for a selection of similar issues, not all due to the same cause though, google "unit test appdomainunloadedexception"), short of having some way to suppress this warning itself.

I tried different bindings and transports (includind the [NullTransport](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20709/NullTransport-for-WCF)), but to no avail.

In the end I settled with this "solution":

```
static void PreventPrematureAppDomainUnloadHack()
{
    //
    // When NUnit unloads the test AppDomain, the WCF started IO completion port threads might
    // not have exited yet.
    // That leads to AppDomainUnloadedExceptions being raised after all is said and done.
    // While native NUnit, ReSharper oder TestDriven.NET runners don't show these, VSTest (and
    // TFS-Build) does. Resulting in very annoying noise in the form of build/test warnings.
    //
    // The following code _attempts_ to wait for all completion port threads to end. This is not
    // an exact thing one can do, however we mitigate the risk of going wrong by several factors:
    // (1) This code is only used during Unit-Tests and not for production code.
    // (2) It is only called when the AppDomain in question is about to go away anway.
    //     So the risk of someone starting new IO threads while we're waiting is very
    //     low.
    // (3) Finally, we have a timeout in place so that we don't wait forever if something
    //     goes wrong.
    //
    if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.StartsWith("test-domain-", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AppDomainUnloadHack: enabled (use DbgView.exe for details).");
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("AppDomainUnloadHack: enabled for domain '{0}'.", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += (sender, args) =>
        {
            int activeIo;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

            do
            {
                if (sw.Elapsed > timeout)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("AppDomainUnloadHack: timeout waiting for threads to complete.");
                    sw.Stop();
                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(5);

                int maxWorkers;
                int availWorkers;
                int maxIo;
                int availIo;
                ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxWorkers, out maxIo);
                ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availWorkers, out availIo);
                activeIo = maxIo - availIo;

                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("AppDomainUnloadHack: active completion port threads: {0}", activeIo));

            } while (activeIo > 0);

            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("AppDomainUnloadHack: complete after {0}", sw.Elapsed));
        };
    }
}
```

The timeout of 3 seconds is totally arbitrary and so is the wait of 5ms between each retry. Sometimes I do get a "timeout", but most of the time it works.

I make sure that this code is called once for every test assembly (i.e. through a static ctor of a referenced type).

As usual in such cases YMMV.