# How to delay for loop cycles?

Tags: c#, wpf, delay

I have a for loop where I calculate the value of something and display it, for example

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++)        
    {
       rnd = rand.Next(1,10);
       value += i + rnd;
       display.Content = value;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want to see the value overwritten after each cycle, delayed by X seconds, how could I achieve that in WPF?

Comment: Take a look at the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Just delay? A sleep in a thread pool call (or Task) then dispatch to main thread for update. Repetitive? A dispatchedtimer.

Comment: I tried Thread.Sleep(), but it stops the whole thread and then completes the whole loop. Task.Delay() works wonders, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Task.Delay` to execute some code after a period of time.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++)        
    {
       rnd = rand.Next(1,10);
       value += i + rnd;
       display.Content = value;
       await Task.Delay(Timespan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a warning flag in my mind about returning `void` from `async` methods.

Comment: @Jodrell, this was the intended use case for async void (asynchronous event handlers), but yes, it would be a good idea for the OP to eventually split off an async method returning Task from this event handler.  This is still a good simple solution in the interim while the OP is learning.

Comment: @Jodrell This is the event handler for an event.  This exact situation is literally exactly why they made `async void` legal in the first place.

Comment: After research I agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers

Comment: @DanBryant What would that change gain him?

Comment: Thank You for the quick answer, I'm learning c# (and programming in general), sorry for the stupid question. I've googled for about 2 hours and found only complicated and not working solutions :S This one works like a charm

Comment: @Servy, As mentioned in the answer to the question Jodrell linked, the main benefit is to isolate the logic from the event handler (most likely in a View Model if this is eventually moved to an MVVM pattern), which allows for unit testing.  The Task instance can also be used to explicitly handle Exceptions at some specific later point where it makes sense to do so.  Not pressing concerns for the OP at this point, but worth considering in the future.

Comment: @DanBryant The method is already a top level method.  Exception handling would either be done in this method, or by handing any exceptions thrown at an application level.