# Strange Async Warning in VS 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, event-handling, async-await

I have a `Button` on a `UserControl`.

I'm marking the `UserControl`'s `Click` event handler for the `Button` as `Async`, so I can run an asynchronous method from inside it. I have to do it this way, otherwise the UI blocks and a `ToolStripLabel` on the `Form` doesn't get updated before the `SchedulerNode.Load()` method is called.

Visual Studio isn't liking it very much, but the warning it's returning seems both incorrect and misapplied.

Here's the code:

[image]

And here's the warning:

[image]

Note that VS indicates the correct line number but the wrong file (the designer code). And according to the warning I should make it an `Async Sub`... but it already is.

It looks like this may be a bug in the IDE. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: Have you checked the designer file? Maybe there is an async function there, too?

Comment: @NicoSchertler - Good point, I hadn't. Nevertheless, nothing `Async` is there--the only methods are the standard `InitializeComponent()` and `Dispose()` entries. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: I'm coming from a C# perspective so shouldn't you always return a Task? Void asyncs are supposed to be avoided (no pun). Try making it a function that returns Task.

Comment: @Crowcoder: VB `Sub` = C# `void` (but you knew that). Right, it's best to steer away from `Async Sub`...  *except* for event handlers. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19415703/722393) from our resident Async/Await expert, Stephen Cleary. That said, I did try returning a `Task`; the same IDE warning persists. I'm just about ready to chalk it up as a bug. What happens in your case? Do you get the warning?

Comment: @InteXX: What's in the designer file at line 99?

Comment: @StephenCleary: I modified the main code, so it's reporting line 97 now. Here's the [designer file](http://1drv.ms/1DDekCy). This sure looks like an IDE bug to me. Next up... try to reproduce it in a brand-new project.

Comment: @StephenCleary: OK, I can reproduce it in a new clean project. I'm just about to report this as a VB bug (doesn't occur in C#). I haven't tried it in VS 2015 yet; I haven't installed that and probably won't until RTM. If anyone who's got 2015 already installed could try it in VB it'd help.