# C# how to efficiently wait x seconds

Tags: c#

My algorithm automatically fills metadata in a specific website (using webBrowser). After fill metadata the algorithm press the button send (in website) and it must wait a few seconds for metadata to be analyzed before contiune (this is not part of algorithm, but webpage). The problem is that i have no way to know when metadata analsys finish. I try the next code, which is used to wait for fully loaded webpage before continuing with the processes:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
```

But it's useless becuse metadata analysis is not related to webpage loading.

So, because metadata analysis takes about 20-40 seconds i think that wait about 60 seconds and continue is a good solution. I try:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
```

After programmatically press button "send", but for anyreason this wait for 60 seconds before button is pressed.

Comment: post the method that calls the button

Comment: Any solution in which the program is intentionally set to hang for a full minute is not a good solution.

Comment: It looks like you are doing automation with pure c#, I don't know why but my suggestion is to know which behavior you want to focus on. after pressing the buttons is there going to be a url change? a pixel change?

Comment: what you are doing on metadata analysis?

Comment: Can you post more snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I completely understand *why* you're wanting to do what you're asking for here, so I'm attempting to answer this question with what information I have here.

If you're calling `Thread.Sleep` in an event handler (say, an event handler for a Button's click event), `Thread.Sleep` will effectively pause the program, since you're still on the UI thread. I'm guess this isn't what you're after?

If you want the UI thread to continue (where you're probably doing the bulk of your work), you'll need to make the Button's click handler async, and use `await Task.Delay` instead. You can see the pattern in use here: [Should I avoid 'async void' event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers)

Additionally, you can probably figure out a way to call back into your application using techniques detailed here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication

Using that method, I'm sure you can get rid of the waiting altogether.