# Async Event on C# Best Practice Confusion

Tags: c#, t-sql, events, asynchronous, event-handling

I have some doubt related to some best practices regarding the asynchronous events. More exactly related to assigning the `async` modifier to a void method (that triggers an `EventHandler`)

My app's supposed to work to do some tests on the background and when I finish up the execution to upload my results to my Db.

Before asking the question I've taken a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers#_=_) but I still feel that I am doing something wrong.

From what I've tested there is no apparent reason (for my specific case)  to apply the `async` modifier when I am calling the event handler because specifying the `async` modifier to `subscriber's` underlying methods it'll 'dial-back' when meeting the first `await` resuming the program execution until the awaited action finishes up, working perfectly as I wanted.

My doubt came when I started applying (1'st approach) the `async` modifier to a void method (the `WorkerClass`) even though it's the event handler, am I doing it wrongly ?

I've done the following test : 
Made a stored procedure which delays it's execution for about a minute

```
alter procedure TestStoredProcedure
    @WhileValue int
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    begin transaction
    begin try

        waitfor delay '00:01';

        insert into WhileResults(Value)
            values
                (@WhileValue)

        commit tran;
    end try
    begin catch
        raisError('Error',16,1);
        rollback tran;
    end catch;

    return;
end
go
```

This is my 1'st approach :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workerClass = new WorkerClass();
            var engine = new PlaybackEngine();
            engine.TestFinishedEventHandler += workerClass.WorkSomething;

            engine.TestRun();
        }
    }


    class PlaybackEngine
    {
        public EventHandler TestFinishedEventHandler;

        public void TestRun()
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < 10000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;    

                OnTestFinishedEventHandler(i,new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnTestFinishedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            TestFinishedEventHandler?.Invoke(sender,args);
        }

    }

    class WorkerClass
    {
        public async void WorkSomething(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await UploadToDbAsync((int)sender);
        }

        private async Task UploadToDbAsync(int i)
        {
            using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=EDWARD;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=True"))
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConn;
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 1000000;

                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = "dbo.TestStoredProcedure";

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhileValue", i);

                await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

My second approach is :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workerClass = new WorkerClass();
            var engine = new PlaybackEngine();
           // engine.TestFinishedEventHandler += workerClass.WorkSomething;
            engine.TestFinished += workerClass.WorkSomething;

            engine.TestRun();
        }
    }

    class PlaybackEngine
    {
        public delegate Task TestRunEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
        public event TestRunEventHandler TestFinished;
        public void TestRun()
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < 10000)
            {        
                /* Doing some work here */        
                i++; 
                OnTestRan(i,new EventArgs());
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        protected virtual async void OnTestRan(object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            //await TestFinished?.Invoke(source, EventArgs.Empty);
            if (TestFinished != null)
                await TestFinished(source, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    class WorkerClass
    {
        public async Task WorkSomething(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await UploadToDbAsync((int)sender);
        }

        private async Task UploadToDbAsync(int i)
        {
            using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=EDWARD;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=True"))
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConn;
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 1000000;

                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = "dbo.TestStoredProcedure";

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhileValue", i);

                await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My doubt came when I started applying (1'st approach) the async modifier to a void method (the WorkerClass) even though it's the event handler, am I doing it wrongly ?

No, you're doing it correctly and you should not have any doubts.
You should avoid using async void, unless it's an event handler. That's the only acceptable place to use async void.

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) - You should read this article if you are interested in more best practices about asynchronous programming.