# Task has a wrong return type

Tags: c#, wpf, task

What wrong? and how to fix??I'm trying to learn a new subject in c#-task. and when I run I got error message:
`Error CS0407 'Task MainWindow.btn1_ClickAsync(object, RoutedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type`

```
 public async Task btn1_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                txtState.Text = "btn1_Click started";
               await LongRunningFunc1();
                txtState.Text = "btn1_Click finished";

            }

        private async Task LongRunningFunc1()
        {
            txt1.Text = "Processing 1 .....";
            btn1.Content = "Wait";
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            txt1.Text = "Hello From Func1";
            btn1.Content = "Click";
        }
```

wpf designer:

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="txtState" Margin="265,10,274,356"/>
        <TextBlock Name="txt1" Height="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.966,-0.95" Margin="281,68,320,301"/>
        <TextBlock Name="txt2" Height="50" Margin="253,238,274,131" />
        <Button Name="btn1" Background="Red" Margin="281,127,300,208" Click="btn1_ClickAsync"></Button>
        <Button Name="btn2" Background="Aqua" Margin="298,309,311,27"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: No `Task` in your Button Click event. Just `async`. It's an event handler. Returns nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I avoid 'async void' event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers)

Answer (score 38):

Button click events are one of the few method signatures where `async void` is acceptable. Change your method to read

```
public async void btn1_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

and you should be OK.

Comment: yes thanks it is work but we need to ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %> on asp.net page

Answer (score 8):

Event handlers need to be `async void` methods:

```
public async void btn1_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it's an event handler it should be `async void`

```
public async void btn1_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Note that `async void` is a special case and should normally be avoided. See [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void) for details.

Answer (score 3):

WPF events are usually [`RoutedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventhandler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), i.e. they have the signature `void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`. Your `btn1_ClickAsync` doesn't match that, hence the error message.

You can fix it by using `public async void btn1_ClickAsync(...)`. Event handlers are also about the only time you would use an `async void` function.