# Complex task has wrong return type

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

First, this post (which deals with event handlers) does not solve my problem:
[Task has a wrong return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024766/task-has-a-wrong-return-type)

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<int> ImportRulesAsync() {
    Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOption>> taskSpecialPaintData = new Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOption>>(populateSpecialPaintOptions);
    taskSpecialPaintData.Start();

    [various processing here...]

    await taskSpecialPaintData;
    [processing that depends on above task to complete]
    return x;
}

private Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOption>> populateSpecialPaintOptions() {
    [sql query here]
    var dtJoin = Common.GetDataTableAsync(sql,  r => new SpecialPaintOption {x = Common.SafeTrim(r["x"]) });
    return dtJoin;
}
```

`dtJoin` is of type `Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOption>>`. `GetDataTableAsync` has the same return type:

[image]

I get the following compile error:

> populateSpecialPaintOptions() has the wrong return type

The compiler is complaining about this line:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

When I change my signature to:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOption> populateSpecialPaintOptions() {...}
```

... the compiler complains about `return dtJoin;`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to
>   'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary'

**EDIT 2**

I don't know how to add a screenshot in a comment, so this is in response to Peter's suggestion to use `.Run()` which my VS2019 code completion doesn't know about:

[image]

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. The `Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOptions>>` constructor requires a method that returns a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOptions>>`, not a task that returns that type. Beyond that, it's not clear what you hope to gain by wrapping that method in a task. ...

Comment: ... Ironically, had you used `Task.Run()`, which is the current recommended way to start a task, the framework would have unwrapped the task for you, but would have hidden the completely superfluous nature of the task from you. Why not just set your `taskSpecialPaintData` variable to the returned value from the `populateSpecialPaintOptions()` method?

Comment: Task.Run() requires an arg. Compiler doesn't like no args on that.

Comment: Of course it requires an arg. So? Pass it an arg! (i.e. the method group name, which will be implicitly converted to a delegate instance for the task)

Comment: @HerrimanCoder why would you run it with no args?  Pass the Task instance or `Func<Task<T>>` or [anything else you can pass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#definition)

Comment: Actually `.Run()` doesn't even exist. Closest option is `.RunSynchronously()`. I'm using .NET 4.7.1. Apologies for my ignorance...but would an example be too much to ask? What should my offending line(s) be changed to? What I'm trying to accomplish is for `populateSpecialPaintOptions()` to run in the background while execution continues. I have no doubt there are better ways, I'm new to `Tasks`. I'm open to any advice.

Comment: _"Actually .Run() doesn't even exist"_ -- of course it does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run__1_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___ Introduced in .NET 4.5 and certainly available in .NET 4.7.1. _"What should my offending line(s) be changed to?"_ -- I've already explained: get rid of the new `Task` object altogether. Your method already returns one. Use _that_ one.

Comment: Peter, what do you mean by `get rid of the new Task object altogether.` If I do that, how will anything run async? How will it run in the background? You're saying to get rid of this entire line?: `Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOption>> taskSpecialPaintData = new Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, SpecialPaintOption>>(populateSpecialPaintOptions);` -- or are you saying not to wrap it in `Task`? When I don't wrap it in `Task` then it can't be a task and run in the background. Apologies for my confusion. Can you please give an example of what you mean?

Comment: _"If I do that, how will anything run async?"_ -- the method already returns a task. This implies that the method itself is already run asynchronously. If it's not doing that, then **that is a completely different question**. The answer to the question you've asked here is found in the two marked duplicates, which directly address the discrepancy between the method that returns a task, and the constructor overloads that expect a method that returns the value your new task is supposed to produce.

Comment: If you method isn't asynchronous enough for you at the moment, then part or all of that method needs to be executed asynchronously. Since you didn't provide the actual body of the method, it's not possible to say whether that's necessary never mind how you should do it. The one program statement you provided (the call to `GetDataTableAsync()`) is already asynchronous.

Comment: As far as the "missing" `Run()` method goes, you need to read the documentation more closely. The `Run()` method is static, called like `Task.Run(...)`. You won't find it as a valid method on a `Task` _instance_. It's fine to rely on the IDE's features (like IntelliSense), but only to the extent that you already know the language and frameworks you're using well enough to properly interpret what those features are telling you. If you get conflicting results **you need to dig deeper** instead of assuming that something doesn't exist even though others have told you it does.

Comment: This did the trick: `var taskSpecialPaintData = Task.Run(() => getSpecialPaintOptionsData() );` - and this was not a duplicate question.