# Run multiple actions in parallel in C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I have the below code in a ASP.Net web forms page which basically checks if some value is in cache and if not it calls a method which gets the data and then stores it in Cache. The method which gets the data is below

```
ChartRenderingHelper.GenerateBidsStatusCreated(currYear.ToString(), currQuarter.ToString(), currYearType.ToString())
```

calls a Stored proc using EF and these 3 calls all call separate SP's..Now I am doing it sequentially so if each SP takes 5 seconds the total operation takes 15..I was thinking of using some Tasks to run these in parallel but not sure how I can change my current code to do that.

```
  bidsCreated.Value = DashboardCacheHelper.IsIncache(bidsCreatedKey, useCaching) ? DashboardCacheHelper.GetFromCache(bidsCreatedKey) : (string)DashboardCacheHelper.SaveCache(bidsCreatedKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChartRenderingHelper.GenerateBidsStatusCreated(currYear.ToString(), currQuarter.ToString(), currYearType.ToString())), DateTime.Now.AddDays(cacheDays));
            bidsSubmitted.Value = DashboardCacheHelper.IsIncache(bidsSubmittedKey, useCaching) ? DashboardCacheHelper.GetFromCache(bidsSubmittedKey) : (string)DashboardCacheHelper.SaveCache(bidsSubmittedKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChartRenderingHelper.GenerateBidsStatusSubmitted(currYear.ToString(), currQuarter.ToString(), currYearType.ToString())), DateTime.Now.AddDays(cacheDays));
            bidsClosed.Value = DashboardCacheHelper.IsIncache(bidsClosedKey, useCaching) ? DashboardCacheHelper.GetFromCache(bidsClosedKey) : (string)DashboardCacheHelper.SaveCache(bidsClosedKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChartRenderingHelper.GenerateBidsStatusClosed(currYear.ToString(), currQuarter.ToString(), currYearType.ToString())), DateTime.Now.AddDays(cacheDays));
```

How can I do these 3 assignments in parallel? Using TPL I know we can run methods in parallel

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

Is this the recommended approach and if I have say 12 operations that need to run in parallel all calling SQL Stored Procs using EF would that be an issue in performance.

Comment: You could use [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run__1_System_Func___0__) and then [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen EF has async methods so you don't need `Task.Run`, OP uses ASP.Net so `Task.WaitAll` will lead to deadlocks - not exactly sure if your suggestion is actively evil or just … not well thought out?

Comment: Do not use Parallel directly in ASP.Net pages, as threads could be suspended without finishing the job, and it doesn't work correctly with `async` methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use asynchrony to achieve this, however it's best to have an asynchronous implementation of your Entity Framework code for adding and fetching.

Firstly, I have refactored the code to reduce duplication and make it more readable by introducing a method `GetOrAddAsync`, this method accepts the cache key, a boolean for `useCaching` (what ever this is for?) and a delegate for the `ChartRenderingHelper` methods. It's not immediately clear what type `currQuarter` and `currYearType` are.

```
private async Task<string> GetOrAddAsync(string cacheKey, bool useCaching, int cacheDays, DateTime currYear, ? currQuarter, ? currYearType, Action<string, string, string> cacheFactory)
{
    if(DashboardCacheHelper.IsIncache(cacheKey, useCaching))
    {
        return DashboardCacheHelper.GetFromCache(cacheKey);
    }

    return (string)(await DashboardCacheHelper.SaveCacheAsync(bidsClosedKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cacheFactory(currYear.ToString(), currQuarter.ToString(), currYearType.ToString())), DateTime.Now.AddDays(cacheDays)).ConfigureAwait(false))
}
```

With the above method, your assignment code then becomes

```
var bidsCreatedCacheTask = GetOrAddAsync(bidsCreatedKey, useCaching, cacheDays, currYear, currQuarter, currYearType, ChartRenderingHelper.GenerateBidsStatusCreated);
var bidsSubmittedCacheTask = GetOrAddAsync(bidsSubmittedKey, useCaching, cacheDays, currYear, currQuarter, currYearType, ChartRenderingHelper.GenerateBidsStatusSubmitted);
var bidsClosedCacheTask = GetOrAddAsync(bidsClosedKey, useCaching, cacheDays, currYear, currQuarter, currYearType, ChartRenderingHelper.GenerateBidsStatusClosed);

await Task.WhenAll(bidsCreatedCacheTask, bidsSubmittedCacheTask, bidsClosedCacheTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

bidsCreated.Value = await bidsCreatedCacheTask;
bidsSubmitted.Value = await bidsSubmittedCacheTask;
bidsClosed.Value = await bidsClosedCacheTask;
```

One key thing to remember is to mark your calling method as `async`, if it's an event handler then it'll be `async void` - but please bare in mind that `async void` [should otherwise be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415703/5062791) in any method that isn't an event handler - because you're constrained to a `void` return type with an event handler.

As LeBigCat has pointed out in the comments, `ConfigureAwait` should be used with asynchronous code that runs on .NET Framework to prevent deadlocks, read [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) to see why.

Comment: I would add .configureAwait(false). OP need also to be sure the data he want to write in the cache are threadsafe.

Comment: He is using  web forms page

Comment: I did realize that after I'd posted that comment, along with the `.net-4.5` tag. Updated code.

Comment: To include it in my Page_Load function I have marked it as async..I hope that's ok

Comment: That should be fine, if it's an event handler then `async void`, otherwise if it has a return type it'll be `async Task<T>`