# Software freeze after Puppeteer launch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, puppeteer-sharp

I have created a small application which should get some data from internet trought `Puppeteer Sharp`, the problem's that after I instantiate the browser the software freeze without no error.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Handler Handler { get; } = new Handler();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Handler.Init(Handler).Wait();
    }
}
```

as you can see I have `Handler` which contains all the properties of the software:

```
public class Handler
{
    private static Url URL = new Url("https://www.diretta.it/");
    public static Browser Browser { get; set; }

    public async Task<bool> Init(Handler prop)
    {
        DotNetEnv.Env.Load("./config.env");

        // The problem's here
        Browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = true,
            ExecutablePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CHROME_PATH"),
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

where `CHROME_PATH` is this: `CHROME_PATH="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"`

what I did wrong? I have the latest version of `Chrome` and `PuppeteerSharp` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Window_Loaded` event method to `async` and do an `await` on the `Init` method, Event Handler methods are an exception. using `async void` instead of `async Task` is ok in this scenario. - Reference ([Should I avoid 'async void' event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers)):

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{  
   await Handler.Init(Handler);
}
```