# Cannot await 'void'

Tags: c#, async-await

this is my script.

```
        private async void secondmult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sct = sc;
            var secondmultx = secondmult;

            if (player.pcc == 100)
            {
                player.multiplier = 2;
                player.pcc = player.pcc - 100;
                secondmult.Enabled = false;
                sct.Text = player.pcc.ToString();
            }
            else if(player.pcc < 100)
            {
                sc.Text = "X";
                await Thread.Sleep(3000);
                sc.Text = player.pcc.ToString();
            }
            else if(player.pcc > 100)
            {
                player.multiplier = 2;
                player.pcc = player.pcc - 100;
                secondmultx.Enabled = false;
                sct.Text = player.pcc.ToString();
            }
```

There is an error on the line 'await Thread.Sleep(3000);'
It says 'Cannot await 'void''
Please may someone re-do the script for me so it works?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(3000);`

Comment: If you declare that the method is async it should have a return type of Task, else it will not have the behaviour that you expect.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari this is a top-level event handler - it can't be a `Task` - it has to be an `async void`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers

Comment: @Bishan does not apply - the OP has the correct method signature, but calling a *non-awaitable expression* with an `await` keyword.

Comment: I know I mistook the error with a compiler warning that I remember seeing

Comment: Use Task.Delay()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread.sleep(3000) is not awaitable. Your method is async so ideal implementation will be await Task.Delay(3000)

**Thread.Sleep** is going to block your current thread and **Task.Delay** is going to delay logically without blocking your current thread.

Thread.sleep should not be used in asynchronous operation instead we should use Task.Delay(3000) and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.Sleep()` is not [awaitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#awaitable-expressions). Use `Task.Delay()` instead.