# How to run async methods inside OnElementChanged method in a custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I need to run an async method in a custom renderer inside the `OnElementChanged` method; however, this method does not have an async signature. What's the recommended way to do async here? Is this method simply an event handler and can we modify the signature to `async void OnElementChanged`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [VisualElementRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/80a4dbfb1cd897f478c38d0aafa6a5d67940d2f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/FastRenderers/VisualElementRenderer.cs#L22) and  [IVisualElementRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/80a4dbfb1cd897f478c38d0aafa6a5d67940d2f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/IVisualElementRenderer.cs#L21)

`OnElementChanged` is an `EventHandler` so you can modify it signature with async like any other EventHandler [Should I avoid 'async void' event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers)