# Assing values from Dictionary to IList (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, task

I got interface with method:

```
Task<Dictionary<long, Cars>> GetCars();
```

Thne I have VM:

```
private IList<Cars> m_cars;

public IList<Cars> MyCars
{
   get => m_cars;
}
```

and some method:

```
public override void Load()
{
  MyCars = someservice.GetCars();
}
```

But I can't do that. How to assing values from `Dictionary` to `IList`?

Comment: `GetCars` is asynchronous and `Load` isn't. Does `GetCars` need to be asynchronous, and if so, are you able to make `Load` asynchronous also?

Comment: @Self Partially, but `GetCars` returns `Task<Dictionary<long, Cars>>` not `Dictionary<long, Cars>`.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't change `Load()`

Comment: Then you probably should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Comment: No ones going to mention `how to assing values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async override void Load()
{
    var dictionary = await someservice.GetCars();
    MyCars = dictionary.Values.ToList();
}
```

If you for some unknown reason can't mark the method as `async` and therefor can't call `await` you have to call the asynchronous method `GetCars()` synchronously, which isn't really recommended because why is it asynchronous when you call it synchronously.

To do this you can simply call the `.Result` of the `Task`

```
public override void Load()
{
    MyCars = someservice.GetCars().Result.Values.ToList();
}
```

Here a demonstration of the given options

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XCqiLY

Comment: `async void`? Now what happens if `MyCars` is accessed again before `GetCars` has completed?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - I assumed Load being an event handler, maybe I am assuming incorrectly - if that isn't the case OP may want to read here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers - about `MyCars` I don't really care what happens in that case, if it isn't populated it will be null, no code of OP would give me any clue if that is okay or not

Comment: Ok, maybe it is, maybe it isn't, but that assumption should have been stated because only event handlers should be `async void`. Also, `MyCars` is get-only so this wouldn't compile.

Comment: But `MyCars = someservice.GetCars();` is in op codes and he say it can't cahnge it so i guess it compile somehow, no? perhaps just an other typo. And the set got deleted

Comment: @Self No, OP's code will definitely not compile for a number of reasons. The OP only stated that the return type of `Load` could not be changed.

Comment: Task...does not containt a def to `Values`

Comment: `Dictionary<long, Cars> = await Task<Dictionary<long, Cars>>` after await it return dictionary, dictionary have `Values`

Comment: @4est - as Genusatplay already mentioned you have to `await` the `Task` this will "resolve" the `Task` and simply return the `Result` of the `Task` which is `Dictionary<long, Cars>` in your case

Comment: @4est - updated my answer