# How to grab an image from url asynchronously in WinForms properly using Tasks

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task-parallel-library

I created a custom control to display an image. The image displayed must be loaded from a website url. I decided to use Tasks to perform the action asynchronously. This is because many images will be loaded during the operation of my program.

```
public Image Image { 
    get => image;
    set {
        image = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
private Image image;

public async void LoadImageAsync(string url)
{
    Image = await GetImageAsync(url);
}

private async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
        return Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

The code above is my current setup. *Is this the correct way to use Tasks?*

I come from JS and Promises so I've taken my knowledge from there. I tested the method and it appears to run correctly in the background. The result image successfully updates the WinForms UI and the `Image` variable is set.

Comment: In WinForms you may have issues with async logic, it might be simpler to do the same thing with synchronous logic, specifically because this is WinForms

Comment: Your code is fine, presuming `void LoadImageAsync(string url)` is a top-level event handler. There's no issue with using `async`/`await` in WinForms

Comment: What is `LoadImageAsync`? How is it used? -- Why do you have  `response.GetResponseStream();` twice there? Is that a copy/paste mistake? -- To download simple images from a known source, use the async methods of WebClient. Use a `static` HttpClient if you may have concurrent downloads that are handled by different instances of that Control. -- The `WebResponse` **must** be disposed.

Comment: Yes it was a duplicate. I fixed it. I will make sure to keep disposal in mind. As I understand it I should use `using` for the response always. I execute `LoadImageAsync` from a top-level event handler as @CoolBots described. Thank you for all the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a question about optimal methods for utilizing Tasks in C#, I have compiled a final version of my code from recommendations made by other answers.

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public Image Image { 
    get => image;
    set {
        image = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
private Image image;

public async void LoadImageAsync(string url)
{
    Image = await GetImageAsync(url);
}

private async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(string url)
{
    using (Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url)) {
        return Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

As per others suggestions this utilizes the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

*Example execution of the `LoadImageAsync` method:*

```
void AnyMethodOrEventHandler()
{
    imageControlInstance.LoadImageAsync("http://someurl.com/image.jpg");
}
```

Thank you all for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use the `void` keyword when you have an async task

Second, you don't need to use the setter to refresh the UI, also is better to use a different name for the Image property.

Third, I suggest using HttpClient instead of WebRequest

```cs
public Image MyImage { get; set; }

public async Task LoadImageAsync(string url)
{
    MyImage = await GetImageAsync(url);
    Refresh();
}
private async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(string url)
{
    var httpClint = new HttpClient();
    var imageBytes = await httpClint.GetStreamAsync(url);
    return Image.FromStream(imageBytes)
}
```

Comment: In WinForms, top-level event handlers *should* be `void`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers

Comment: if it is (doesn't look like) its ok to use void then.

Comment: you can not pass `string url` to the top-level event handler!

Comment: Sure you can - just not into a default `EventHandler` - just define your own

Comment: Op, didn't ask how you can pass it to EvenHandler look at the question again

Answer (score 0):

You're using it properly. Your code illustrates exactly the intended use of `async`/`await`: you can write asynchronous code in the same way you would write synchronous code. You've written easy-to-read code that doesn't lock up your UI while waiting for a response. That's your goal.

If you haven't already, read over Microsoft's documentation on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Just a note on your use of `HttpWebRequest`. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest#remarks) says:

> **Important**
>
> We don't recommend that you use `HttpWebRequest` for new development. Instead, use the [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) class.

If your code is already written, you can leave it be. I'm pretty sure `HttpClient` just uses `HttpWebRequest` in the background anyway. But it's something to think about.