# async use with FileSystemWatcher in Net 5

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-5, filesystemwatcher, blockingcollection

I'm trying to create an application in Net 5 that watches a folder and any time files are being dropped in the folder, it should run a certain set of tasks (getting some info from the files, copy them to new location, among others).
I thought I could implement both Net's `FileSystemWatcher` and concurrent collections (from the `Collections.Concurrent` namespace here, but I run into the problem that I cannot run it with being async.

I initialize the watcher like this (following the docs of MS):

```
public BlockingCollection<string> fileNames = new BlockingCollection<string>();
public void InitiateWatcher()
{
    using FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\temp"); //test dir

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
             | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
             | NotifyFilters.FileName

    watcher.Created += OnCreated;

    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press e to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string value = $"Created: {e.FullPath}";
    // this of course creates problems, since it is a async task running in sync mode.
    await PipelineStages.ReadFilenamesAsync(_sourcePath, fileNames);
    // do other work with the result from ReadFilenameAsync
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

My PipelineStages class, which does most of the real work with the files, looks like this:

```
public static class PipelineStages
{
    public static Task ReadFilenamesAsync(string path, BlockingCollection<string> output)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                output.Add(fileName);
            }
            output.CompleteAdding();
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}
```

If I turn the OnCreated method async it throws error that the return type is not valid. That kinda makes sense to me, although I don't know the way forward on this.

I see two errors:
One error is when the code hits the `output.add(fileName)` line, it throws an `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The collection has been marked as complete with regards to additions.'`

The other one is that I notice in the onCreated method that filenames get written to the console that are in very different folders, seemingly randomly.

So, basically, I have two questions:

- Is this the right approach? (If not, what are other alternatives)
- If this is the right approach, how can I fix these problems?

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` handlers should do as little as possible and return as quickly as possible.  A better approach IMO is to dump off the notification to another thread.  I personally use an instance of the `System.Threading.Channels.Channel` class.  Each one of my `FileSystemWatcher` event-handlers takes the event data, writes it to Channel, and returns.  Meanwhile my main thread has a one-time await-function that continuously monitors the channel (with `await foreach`) and prossesses each notification.

Comment: @Martas `async void ` is generally discouraged.

Comment: @Neil that was my understanding too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I avoid 'async void' event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers)

Comment: Have you tried making the event handler asynchronous, by adding the `async` keyword? `private async void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)` What exactly is the compile error that you got?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias there is no compile error. The error is when running the code: When trying to add the filename to the BlockingCollection<string> output it throws an error System.InvalidOperationException: 'The collection has been marked as complete with regards to additions.' Updated my post.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `output.CompleteAdding();` line?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it  looks like you prematurely call `output.CompleteAdding()`, so every subsequent execution of `PipelineStages.ReadFilenamesAsync` gets the foregoing `System.InvalidOperationException` error.
Secondly, while `async void` is indeed generally discouraged, it is admissible in the following cases:

- event handlers
- the `Main` method

BUT as long as such an `async void` event handler is basically a *fire‑and‑forget* function, you should make it bulletproof with regard to any captured variables whose state can be invalidated in the outer scope (disposed, [CompleteAdding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.completeadding), and the like).
I have rigged up the following *async*‑contrived short self‑contained example to demonstrate the point I am trying to make:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;

object lockObj = new();
using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@".");
using BlockingCollection<string?> queue = new();

async void FileCreatedHandlerAsync(object _, FileSystemEventArgs e) => await Task.Run(() => {
  var lockTaken = false;
  try
  {
    Monitor.Enter(lockObj, ref lockTaken);
    if (!queue.IsCompleted)
      queue.Add(e.Name);
  }
  catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
  finally {
    if (lockTaken)
      Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
  }
});
watcher.Created += FileCreatedHandlerAsync;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

var consumer = Task.Run(async () => {
  foreach (string? name in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"File has been created: \"{name}\"."));
  
  Debug.Assert(queue.IsCompleted);
});

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();

watcher.Created -= FileCreatedHandlerAsync;
lock (lockObj) {
  queue.CompleteAdding();
}
bool completed = consumer.Wait(100);
Debug.Assert(completed && TaskStatus.RanToCompletion == consumer.Status);
```