# how can I pause the main thread, while I am updating my WPF components?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to update a TextBox to display 3-2-1 and then I play a sound. This works sort of, but my sound starts to play immediately, because the Threads are not blcoking the main thread. I tried to add another Thread.Sleep(4000); in he main thread, but then it all just waits and the textbox does not display running numbers. I get number 1 in the textbox and the sound plays :(

So how do I pause the main thread, while the TextBox runs 3-2-1 and then sound?

´´´
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
try
{

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async (o) =>
```

{
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "3"));

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "2"));
await Task.Delay(1000);
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "1"));
await Task.Delay(3000);
```

});

Task.Delay(3000);

```
    if (waveOut!=null ) waveOut.Stop(); 

    Songs = db.Songs; 
    int r = rnd.Next(Songs.Count);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r);

    String name = ((Song)Songs[r]).Name1;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);

    int start = ((Song)Songs[r]).Start1;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(start);

    waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
    

    var ms = File.OpenRead("C:\\"+name);
    var rdr = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
    var wavStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(rdr);
    wavStream.Skip(start);
    var baStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(wavStream);
    
    waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
    
        waveOut.Init(baStream);

    
    
    waveOut.Play();
        
    /*
        while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
      */  
    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

}

´´´

Comment: Show the complete code of the method including its declaration and how this method is called.

Comment: Usually one would try to avoid stopping the main thread to avoid making the App unresponsive. You could instead `await Task.Run(yourActions and the Thread.Sleep)`. The await will make it so that your actions are run in another thread but after the action the code resum after the `await` which is what you want.

Comment: That is the complete code. It is called from the Button's "Click". Cannot use await. It says I cannot use async method in main thread

Comment: This seems to do the trick! ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async (o) =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "3"));
    
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "2"));
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "1"));
    await Task.Delay(3000);
});

Task.Delay(3000);

Comment: Hmm it seems Code-block is not accepting my code :(

Comment: Oh no it does not work. The music starts to play instantly :(

Comment: @wellumies : "It says I cannot use async method in main thread" : yes you can. What it is probably saying is that you can't use `await` if the method is not `async` so just make the signature `private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`.
Usually we avoid `async void` but in you case it will be [just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415703/13448212) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your event handler with the `async` keyword and await the `Delay` calls before you play the sound:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        outputTextBox.Text = "3";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        outputTextBox.Text = "2";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        outputTextBox.Text = "1";
        await Task.Delay(1000);

    // play sound:

        if (waveOut!=null)
            waveOut.Stop();

        Songs = db.Songs;
        int r = rnd.Next(Songs.Count);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r);

        String name = ((Song)Songs[r]).Name1;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);

        int start = ((Song)Songs[r]).Start1;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(start);

        waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());


        var ms = File.OpenRead("C:\\"+name);
        var rdr = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
        var wavStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(rdr);
        wavStream.Skip(start);
        var baStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(wavStream);

        waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());

        waveOut.Init(baStream);

        waveOut.Play();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

There is no reason to involve the thread pool here.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, just use [async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios). I strongly recommend reading the documentation about it since you seem confused about its use.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
        // The await call will make it wait until the task is completed
        // (including the delay of 3 seconds) then it will resume the execution
        // of the code after the `await`. 
        await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "3"));
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "2"));
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "1"));
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            });

        this.PlaySong();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What is interesting with `async` `await` is that it won't pause the main thread so your app will not appear unresponsive.