# Postgres and scoped_session, but still got FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using sqlalchemy `sessionmaker` and `scoped_session` to create a pool of connection for my threads so that I can avoid the error in the title, but unfortunately I still get it. I have been reading similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847144/heroku-psql-fatal-remaining-connection-slots-are-reserved-for-non-replication) and reading [blogs](https://copdips.com/2019/05/using-python-sqlalchemy-session-in-multithreading.html) but unfortunately I still can't get my head around the problem.
My app is listening on a pubsub and writes some stuff in the database when data arrives. The app gets loads of messages, and therefore after a certain number I would get the error. I thought that using `sessionmaker` and `scoped_session` would easily handle the situation, but I am obviously missing something. 
Here is the simplified code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

TOPIC_SUBSCRIBER = os.environ.get('PUBSUB_SUBSCRIBER')
PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get('PROJECT_ID')
client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = client.subscription_path(PROJECT_ID, TOPIC_SUBSCRIBER)

db_uri = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI')
engine = create_engine(db_uri)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

def event_handler(message):

    session_db = Session()

    # Do stuff

    Session.remove()


def run():
    streaming_pull_future = client.subscribe(
        subscription_path, callback=event_handler
    )
    print("Listening for messages on {}".format(subscription_path))

    # Calling result() on StreamingPullFuture keeps the main thread from
    # exiting while messages get processed in the callbacks.
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except Exception as e:  # noqa
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()
        print("ERROR: {}".format(str(e)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to pubsub creating too many threads and overloading the database with too many connections. I solved it by limiting the number of concurrent messages which can be processed at the same time. The approach is also discussed [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7677). 
Here is my code :

```
def run():
    # Limit the subscriber to only have ten outstanding messages at a time.
    flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=MAX_WORKERS)
    custom_executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS)
    custom_scheduler = pubsub_v1.subscriber.scheduler.ThreadScheduler(custom_executor)

    streaming_pull_future = client.subscribe(
        subscription_path, callback=callback, flow_control=flow_control, scheduler=custom_scheduler
    )
    print("Listening for messages on {}".format(subscription_path))

    # Calling result() on StreamingPullFuture keeps the main thread from
    # exiting while messages get processed in the callbacks.
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except Exception as e:  # noqa
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()
        print("ERROR: {}".format(str(e)))
```

The code above fixed the problem, however I thought that `sessionmaker` and `scoped_session` would manage the concurrency by themself, instead I had to handle it somewhere else. I would love to hear some SQLAlchemy expert opinion on this.
I hope this would help someone in the future.