# psql: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, connection-pooling

I want to understand when this error occurs and how to resolve it. I checked `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks` but couldnt figure out which process is exhausing the connections

We are using sqlalchemy to connect to database as below

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine_url = f'{dbms}://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database}'

engine = create_engine(engine_url, pool_size=20, max_overflow=10)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

db_session = Session()
```

This is an extension of [Heroku "psql: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847144/heroku-psql-fatal-remaining-connection-slots-are-reserved-for-non-replication)

Comment: Probably something doesn't close connections properly, so your are running out of database connections. This condition is known as a *connection leak*.

Comment: Exactly! I want to find the applications that's causing this connection leak. Is there a way to find out that?

Comment: You said you checked `pg_stat_activity`. That's all the information about the existing clients you get: process id, client address, user, database. You'll have to investigate the client side.

Comment: Is there a way to get client process id which creates a lot of connections from this pg_stat_activity pid?

Comment: No. That is often on a different machine. Use `lsof` to see who holds a network connection to the database. Use `pg_terminate_backend` to kill database sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the client process id in application name of sqlalchemy engine url. This will be stored under `application_name` in `pg_stat_activity` and it will be helpful to debug from where did this connection was opened.

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

client_hostname = os.environ.get('HOSTNAME', 'UNKNOWN')
client_pid = os.getpid()


engine_url = f'{dbms}://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database}?application_name={client_hostname}_{client_pid}'

engine = create_engine(engine_url, pool_size=20, max_overflow=10)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

db_session = Session()
```

This shows where the connection was originated from and the application name has a limit of [64 chars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING), so we can include any custom information that you want to pass on to db stats