# How much time Django take to make a connection with PostgreSQL when both are on the same machine?

Tags: django, postgresql

For my application, it is taking 14ms to make a connection between Django and PostgreSQL,my system is 40 core cpu and 16 GB ram, can we reduce this time? Thank you

Comment: if the time to acquire a connection is an issue, you can use either [pgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/) or [db-pool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-pool). Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419665/how-does-pgbouncer-help-to-speed-up-django)