# Configuring django in heroku for a lot of requests per minute

Tags: django, heroku, configuration, web-deployment

I have a instance of django deployed in Heroku as follow, Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput ; gunicorn MY_APP.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A MY_APP worker
beat: celery -A MY_APP beat
```

This instance can receive 2000-4000 requests per minute, and sometimes it is too much.

I know I should change the communications... but can I change something in the configuration to get a 10-30% in the  server efficiency?

Comment: When you say "requests", you mean http requests? These are all requests for django, or do they include requests for static files? Do many of these requests result in a celery task, and how heavy are these celery tasks?

Comment: Yes, http requests. These http requests are without static files, because the django server is an API with django rest framework. And very few requests result in a celery task (1% - 5%). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that springs to mind is to check out connection pooling and/or persistent database connections.  Depending on how much database access your app is using, this could significantly increase the number of RPM your app is able to handle.

Check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125504/django-persistent-database-connection) for some good ideas, in particular the following answers:

- [persistent connections, available since Django 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438241/3231557)
- [PgBouncer, a lightweight connection pooler for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698102/3231557)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of Heroku is that you can dynamically scale your app. You can spin up new web workers with `heroku ps:scale web+1` for example.

Comment: Yes, of course. I know it :-) But I don't know if I can configure better the server too. Do you know a better configuration?